# update property using map versus object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I use redux I have to care for immutable object, but in pure react, I often update my property in arrays using map

```
handleAgeChangedUser = e => {
    const { users, selectedUser } = this.state;

    this.setState(
      {
        users: users.map(o => {
          return o.id === selectedUser.id ? selectedUser : o;
        })
      },
      () => {
        this.ageInput.value = "";
      }
    );
  };
```

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/z358py2y2p

What's the limitation of this approach and what's other alternative? I remember without es6, I have to use loadash, or worse, back in the day I have to findIndex, then loop manually just to do this simple operation.

Comment: Only issue that I think with this approach would come if you have huge users base. Then it will loop through entire array even if you want to update the first value. Imagine same code for Facebook. It will be a nightmare. My suggestion, use a `for` loop if you have huge users. Else its should trouble much. Also, `o` is a bad name in this context, in my POV. You could use `users.map(user => user.id === selectedUser.id ? selectedIser : user );`

Comment: o means object, what's the `good name` for it?

Comment: Though it was an opinionated comment, what does *object* mean inside `map`? Since you have written code, you know what it is, but a third person will have to lookup to check what it is and what it means. Having `user.id ===` instead of `o.id ===` makes more sense. But again, this is also an opinionated comment.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the limitation of this approach and what's other alternative?

There are two aspects in question - pure technical and architectural.

First, `React` performs shallow comparation by default and it's not recommend to implement deep equal logic (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate ), that's why `immutable`-like solutions (`immutable.js`, `seamless-immutable`) allows to solve that problem without harming performance.

Second, state-ful components itself is bad architectural solution, because of business logic is distributed between many components and data flow is not unidirectional, which is incompatible with functional approach. So, `flux`-based solution with immutable provider is best.

Comment: the second point sounds irrelevant, im not asking architectural related question. But thanks for pointing the first one, like it.

Answer (score 0):

While mutuating, you were using the same memory allocation of the state, that is you were using same reference of the state.

Eg: `

```
var x = 10;
    x = 20;
```

Here x value is changed to 20 at the same memory space allocated.  You are actually changing the data but not reference here.  Think 'x' as an big object and you are making a change to the deepest key value pair.  Since you were making change at the same reference of the state.  React finds it difficult to understand that whether a change has been made to the state.

Instead if you create an new copy(memory reference) of the state and update the values in it.  It actually refers a different memory location (memory reference) and react easily understands that there is a change in state.

In our case, it works fine.  But while processing bigger data.  We would face issue

> Other than these, you can use 'Object.assign()' for objects, for arrays
>   you need to take a copy and do your changes on that :-)

`

Comment: so any alternative?

Comment: For objects you can use 'Object.assign()' method.  For arrays, you need to take a copy and do your changes on that

Comment: can include that in the answer?